# How to get infected with Antivirus 2010

Tags: installation, anti-virus, virus

I know that this is the exact oposite of the question most people ask as it is a royal pain to remove.  I hope this isn't flagged as me wanting to infect other people.  I know my mom almost installed it but it was running firefox so she unknowingly downloaded it 10 times but didn't install it.  I have since deleted those files and have been wondering what to look out for on sites that carry the virus.  I'd like to test out AV software in a VM environment.  It has been getting past our AVG as of late.

Thanks,

Comment: Try this question on http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Don't cross post, the question will be moved shortly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with seeking knowledge.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the following:

1. Search Google for "boobs".
2. Visit the top 20 hits and on each of the 20, click on 10 links.

If you aren't infected after that, I'll be shocked.

Comment: Upvoting for boobs

Comment: upvoted the upvote...boobs

Comment: wait..is this reddit?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. If you want malware samples go on Google and browse for XXX content. Some people even get paid, so called "Researchers".

Comment: Upvoting for boobs (and upvoting all those that mentioned they upvoted for boobs). Seriously, though, be sure to use Internet Explorer (any version, all are sh*te) for best chances of achieving your desired results. Be absolutely certain you do this in a VM.

Answer (score 5):

Plenty of bad links can be found on

http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php

http://www.malwaredomains.com/

http://www.malwaredomains.com/wordpress/?cat=5 is the rogue av category.

Comment: Nicely done; upvoted. @PHLiGHT: You might want to use these resources as well as the above answer (re boobs).

Answer (score 3):

You can also download eicar.com from http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm.  It's a virus test file.  All anti-virus software should detect it, but it is harmless.

Not as much fun as boobs, perhaps, but more likely to meet with your mom's approval, and safe to do directly on the machine you want to test.